# Missing county in Google Maps geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I've noticed that a handful of zip codes are not returning a county. For example, 30601 (Athens, GA - county is Clarke) json result below. Normally I see county data returned with type `administrative_area_level_2`. This is missing from the response:

```
$url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=30601&key=topsecretkey 

Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [address_components] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => 30601
                                    [short_name] => 30601
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => postal_code
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Athens
                                    [short_name] => Athens
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => locality
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Georgia
                                    [short_name] => GA
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => United States
                                    [short_name] => US
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => country
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [formatted_address] => Athens, GA 30601, USA
                    [geometry] => Array
                        (
                            [bounds] => Array
                                (
                                    [northeast] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 34.0593981
                                            [lng] => -83.288826
                                        )

                                    [southwest] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 33.9479501
                                            [lng] => -83.405851
                                        )

                                )

                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [lat] => 34.006845
                                    [lng] => -83.3468784
                                )

                            [location_type] => APPROXIMATE
                            [viewport] => Array
                                (
                                    [northeast] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 34.0593981
                                            [lng] => -83.288826
                                        )

                                    [southwest] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 33.9479501
                                            [lng] => -83.405851
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [place_id] => ChIJocit0GgT9ogRTBKlRatQYFc
                    [types] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => postal_code
                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => OK
)
```

If I pass a different zip code, say 30083 (Stone Mountain, GA county DeKalb), the county (and `administrative_area_level_2`) is returned as expected.

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [address_components] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => 30083
                                    [short_name] => 30083
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => postal_code
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Stone Mountain
                                    [short_name] => Stone Mountain
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => locality
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => DeKalb County
                                    [short_name] => Dekalb County
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Georgia
                                    [short_name] => GA
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [long_name] => United States
                                    [short_name] => US
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => country
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [formatted_address] => Stone Mountain, GA 30083, USA
                    [geometry] => Array
                        (
                            [bounds] => Array
                                (
                                    [northeast] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 33.8351599
                                            [lng] => -84.1243101
                                        )

                                    [southwest] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 33.7368448
                                            [lng] => -84.246361
                                        )

                                )

                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [lat] => 33.7994803
                                    [lng] => -84.1909841
                                )

                            [location_type] => APPROXIMATE
                            [viewport] => Array
                                (
                                    [northeast] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 33.8351599
                                            [lng] => -84.1243101
                                        )

                                    [southwest] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 33.7368448
                                            [lng] => -84.246361
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [place_id] => ChIJcxoG6teo9YgRwtQgWre-Trk
                    [postcode_localities] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Pine Lake
                            [1] => Stone Mountain
                            [2] => Tucker
                            [3] => Wilshire
                        )

                    [types] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => postal_code
                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => OK
)
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? If no, is there a way to notify Google of this missing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking them up on Google Maps, 30601 goes outside of Clarke County, and thus with just the zip code it's not possible to determine a county value. 30601 appears to include bits of Clarke, Madison, and Jackson counties.

30601 (note the areas in green at the top of the zip code near Sandy Creek Park):

[image]

Clarke County:

[image]

Comment: Passed the entire st address and am now seeing the county - thank you kind individual!

Comment: Great answer! @acoder please also see [Geocoding Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices) as it is best for you to input a non unambiguous address in the Geocoding API. And if in a case where you have to input an ambiguous query, it is recommended that you use Places Autocomplete.